# Creating Table in Wordpress with dbDelta function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to create a custom table in wordpress for a plugin. I followed a few online texts and got the table created, but found that it could not be accessed. When trying to select all from the table, nothing would be returned and when attempting to view the table with the database browser plugin, I received this error: "ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp-typeEvents LIMIT 0, 100' at line 1" in response to the plugin's query ("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM wp-typeEvents LIMIT 0, 100;;").

In short, I'm trying to use dbDelta to create a table. The table is created, but there's some sort of problem that makes it unable to have rows added or to read its contents.

I've read that dbDelta can be finnicky function, so I've tried to stick to its three golden rules:

-Putting each field on a new line
-Putting two spaces between the primary key and its definition
-Having at least one key

Here's the code:

```
global $wpdb;

$tablename = "wp-typeEvents";   
$query = "CREATE TABLE `" . $tablename . "` (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `eventName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `location` varchar(60) DEFAULT '' NULL,
    `price` double NOT NULL,
    `description` text NOT NULL,
    `paypal` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    );";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($query);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Figured out my own problem. The function was choking on the hyphen in the table name.

Answer (score 3):

Do not hard-code the table name, use $wpdb->prefix (as someone else noted).

Do not use quotes around field names.

There are other useful "rules" as well, they are all listed here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

> Note that the dbDelta function is rather picky, however. For instance:
>
> - You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
> - You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.
> - You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
> - Field types must be all lowercase.
> - SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

If it is inside a plugin, the require_once() path is wrong. Should be:

```
require_once('/includes/upgrade.php');
```

Should be corrected to be able to load dbDelta() function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');` is correct.

Comment: Plugin functions are called from the **wp-admin** directory when the plugin is loaded, so there is no need to write the whole path.

Comment: @ninty9notout: Now I understand your point: That is the path in the question. I don't think it was like that when I answered, but I can't remember. Thanks for noting it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Also take notice that the current `dbDelta()` function does not parse the ordering keywords ASC|DESC on the UNIQUE KEY name of the column that it is referencing, It will add the the constraint to the remaining index and therefore it will try to add the constraint triggering a Unique Key error. See the example below:

Try to create this questrong textry will trigger an error.

```
CREATE TABLE wp_test (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (stcr_id),
        UNIQUE KEY uk_email (subscriber_email ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

By default the ordering type is ASC so getting rid of that will work.

```
CREATE TABLE wp_test (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (stcr_id),
        UNIQUE KEY uk_email (subscriber_email))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I tested this on WordPress 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with few issues while using dbDelta core functionality of wordpress and decided to create a function for it:

```
/**
 * Prevents unnecessary re-creating index and repetitive altering table operations when using WordPress dbDelta function
 *
 * Usage Example:
 *
 * $table_name      = "ratings";
 *
 * $table_columns   = "id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
 *                  rate tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 *                  ticket_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 *                  response_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 *                  created_at TIMESTAMP";
 *
 * $table_keys      = "PRIMARY KEY (id),
 *                  KEY ratings_rate (rate),
 *                  UNIQUE KEY ratings_response_id (response_id)";
 *
 * create_table($table_name, $table_columns, $table_keys);
 *
 * Things that need to be considered when using dbDelta function :
 *
 * You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
 * You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.
 * You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
 * You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
 * Field types must be all lowercase.
 * SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase.
 * You must specify the length of all fields that accept a length parameter. int(11), for example.
 *
 * Further information can be found on here:
 *
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins
 *
 * @param $table_name
 * @param $table_columns
 * @param null $table_keys
 * @param null $charset_collate
 * @version 1.0.1
 * @author Ugur Mirza Zeyrek
 */
function create_table($table_name, $table_columns, $table_keys = null, $db_prefix = true, $charset_collate = null) {
    global $wpdb;

    if($charset_collate == null)
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_name = ($db_prefix) ? $wpdb->prefix.$table_name : $table_name;
    $table_columns = strtolower($table_columns);

    if($table_keys)
        $table_keys =  ", $table_keys";

    $table_structure = "( $table_columns $table_keys )";

    $search_array = array();
    $replace_array = array();

    $search_array[] = "`";
    $replace_array[] = "";

    $table_structure = str_replace($search_array,$replace_array,$table_structure);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name $table_structure $charset_collate;";

    // Rather than executing an SQL query directly, we'll use the dbDelta function in wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php (we'll have to load this file, as it is not loaded by default)
    require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    // The dbDelta function examines the current table structure, compares it to the desired table structure, and either adds or modifies the table as necessary
    return dbDelta($sql);
}
```

https://github.com/mirzazeyrek/wordpress_create_table

Answer (score 0):

As well as the issue you have found yourself you appear to be hard coding the table prefix. You should not be doing this. Instead as per the manual you should use :-

```
$wpdb->prefix
```

This stores the prefix and should be prepended to the table name. This allows for the possibility of the prefix changing.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins